# Using a specific app engine version depending on Android app version

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

Scenario: I have an Android app on the market running version code 5 calling on App Engine version 2 (default) using Google Cloud Endpoints and Objectify. I need to make changes to both the Android app the App Engine backend.

Problem:  The new version of the Android app (version 6) will not work with the old version 2 of App Engine since the returned data will be different. The users of my Android app will slowly begin to update to the new version requiring both the old and new version of the App Engine backend to be in use.

Question: Is it possible for the older versions of the Android app to call the older version of App Engine while the newer versions of the Android app call the newer version of App Engine. 
Can the Android client check its version and change the requests made respectively or can App Engine check the request and direct it to the proper version? Or is there an alternate approach to this situation that I am missing?

The Android app is only in alpha testing with < 20 users so it is not detrimental if I put the older version out of commission until all have updated. Though it would be nice to have a solution for future updates that does not temporarily make the app unusable. Perhaps I could tailor my code to handle these situations. I am all ears. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's much, **much** easier to update server code than client code. When migrating APIs, you generally want the server to speak both API versions until you can get the bulk of your clients upgraded. Depending on your audience this might take months.

It's a good idea to build the ability to force upgrade into your client based on a server response.

You generally don't want to have lots of versions of your server code running simultaneously. Data migrations will quickly become impossible to manage. Deal with single server-side version transitions at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the advice.

It turns out I didn't fully understand the difference between backend API versions and App Engine instance versions. After re-reading the documentation several times and combing SO for clues, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314510/how-to-access-specific-google-cloud-endpoints-api-versions-on-android-clients) answer relating to [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/issues/47) github issue.

Now this figure makes a little more sense.

[image]

By incrementing the Endpoint API version in the Endpoint class annotation then rebuilding the client libraries, the Android client (New version) then calls the new API version. Meanwhile, all the existing Android clients running the old API version will still be able to call the older backend API version. Incrementing the App Engine version is a way to manage these API rollouts.

Answer (score 0):

In particular for GAE apps providing Endpoints backends the Endpoints API versioning is designed exactly to handle migrations like the one you mention. You may want to go through [Deploying to multiple app versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/test_deploy#deploying_to_multiple_app_versions).

In general (outside Endpoints) one can implement a graceful client upgrade story based on the GAE automatic [routing via URL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#routing_via_url) which allows reaching a module instance running *a specific version* of the module code (if available):

> ```
> https://version-dot-module-dot-app-id.appspot.com
> http://version.module.app-id.my-custom-domain.com
> ```
>
> Sends the request to an available instance of the named module and version.